How do I implement retrieval in a langchain RunnableWithMessageHistory?
I just started using the langchain js. I want to provide a context on the chat and i don't know how
import { Ollama, OllamaEmbeddings } from '@langchain/ollama';
import { ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder } from '@langchain/core/prompts';
import { RunnableConfig, RunnableWithMessageHistory } from '@langchain/core/runnables';
import { ChatMessageHistory } from '@langchain/community/stores/message/in_memory';
import { DocxLoader } from '@langchain/community/document_loaders/fs/docx';
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from 'langchain/text_splitter';
import { MemoryVectorStore } from 'langchain/vectorstores/memory';

const loader = new DocxLoader('./test.docx');
const model = new Ollama({ model: 'llama3.1' });

const messageHistory = new ChatMessageHistory();


const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
    new MessagesPlaceholder('history'),
    [ 'human', '{input}' ]
]);


const config: RunnableConfig = { configurable: { sessionId: '1' } };

(async () => {
    const docs = await loader.load();

    const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
        chunkSize: 1000,
        chunkOverlap: 200
    });
    const splits = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(docs);
    const vectorStore = await MemoryVectorStore.fromDocuments(
        splits,
        new OllamaEmbeddings()
    );
    const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever(); // What to do with this??

    const runnable = prompt.pipe(model);

    const withHistory = new RunnableWithMessageHistory({
        runnable,
        getMessageHistory: (_sessionId: string) => messageHistory,
        inputMessagesKey: 'input',
        historyMessagesKey: 'history'
    });

    let output = await withHistory.invoke(
        { input: 'Hello there, I\'m Archibald!' },
        config
    );

    console.log(output);

    output = await withHistory.invoke(
        { input: 'How are you?' },
        config
    );

    console.log(output);

    output = await withHistory.invoke(
        { input: 'What is my name?' },
        config
    );

    console.log(output);
})()

`
You are an assistant for question-answering tasks.
Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer the question.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know.
If the human sent an open ended query you can have a normal conversation with them.
Do not mention that you are an assistant if the question is not about you.
Use three sentences maximum and keep the answer concise.
    {context}
`;

i tried having using this on system prompt and it gives me an error that the context is not passed, i do not want to pass the context every time i send a prompt
